# How to escape Python boto's SelectExpression for Amazon SimpleDB

Tags: python, python-2.7, boto, boto3, amazon-simpledb

Currently my code is

```
client = boto3.client('sdb')
query = 'SELECT * FROM `%s` WHERE "%s" = "%s"' % (domain, key, value)
response = client.select(SelectExpression = query)
```

The variable `key` and `value` is input by user, what are the best way to escape them in my above code?

Edit: What I concern is how to escape the fields such as we did in the past to prevent SQL injection, but now in SimpleDB

Comment: What is the expected resulting query?

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4451119/2740386 in advance?

Answer (score 4):

Subselects and destructive operations can't be performed using simpledb.

Amazon provides quoting rules: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/QuotingRulesSelect.html

You can apply this behavior in python using this function:

```
def quote(string):
    return string.replace("'", "''").replace('"', '""').replace('`', '``')

client = boto3.client('sdb')
query = 'SELECT * FROM `%s` WHERE "%s" = "%s"' % (quote(domain), quote(key), quote(value))
response = client.select(SelectExpression = query)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you meant `sideffect` of SQL injection is deletion/destruction, SimpleDB only support querying data, if you want to protect data exposing ( that you dont want to ) check aws docs [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl-sql-conditions.html)

Note: Since the guide is good to go, i thought the link is enough